# MonoTouch.Dialog: iPad not getting background Image set

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

using MonoTouch.Dialog I create a simple ViewController:

In the LoadView I set the background image. This works in iPhone, but not in iPad. There is nothing else to the app at this point:

```
public override void LoadView ()
{
    base.LoadView ();
    var color = UIColor.FromPatternImage (image);
    TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    ParentViewController.View.BackgroundColor = color;
}
```

is there a reason why iPads don't get their background set?

Comment: I found that on the ipad TableView's have a different structure. SO to set the background color use: TableView.BackgroundView = new UIView(ParentViewController.View.Frame) {BackgroundColor = color};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the background image of a UITableView in MonoTouch.Dialog on an iPad:

```
TableView.BackgroundView = 
     new UIView(ParentViewController.View.Frame) 
         {BackgroundColor = color};
```

where color is an UIColor image